# Regexp to add attribute in any xml tags

Tags: php, xml, regex

I have well-formed xml documents into string variables. I want to use preg_replace to add a defined attribute to every xml tags.

For example replace:

```
<tag1>
<tag2> some text </tag2>
</tag1>
```

by:

```
<tag1 attr="myAttr">
<tag2 attr="myAttr"> some text </tag2>
</tag1>
```

So I basically need the regex expression to find any start tags and add my attribute, but I'm a complete regex noob.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't use regular expressions for working on xml. Xml is not a regular language. Use the [xml extensions of php](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.construct.php) instead:

```
$xml = new SimpleXml(file_get_contents($xmlFile));
function process_recursive($xmlNode) {
    $xmlNode->addAttribute('attr', 'myAttr');
    foreach ($xmlNode->children() as $childNode) {
        process_recursive($childNode);
    }
}
process_recursive($xml);
echo $xml->asXML();
```

All answers containing regular expressions will break this valid xml, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding='UTF-8'?>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- <meta> ... </meta> -->
        <script>//<![CDATA[
            function load() {document.write('<tt>Test</tt>');}
        //]]></script>
        <title><![CDATA[Fancy <<SiteName>> [with Breadcrumbs] > in > title]]></title>
    </head>
    <body onload="load()">
        <input
            type="submit"
            value="multiline
                   button
                   text"
        />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I understand the dirtiness in using regex for xml, but in my case I'll only try to add those attributes on 'regex safe' xml doc.
Thank you for pointing this out!!

Comment: btw I was surprised by the few code required to do it with simpleXML, I tried your code but it adds a <attributes attr="myAttr"/> element just before the document's end tag, weird

Comment: ok I did some minor changes in that one to work for me, using addAttribute($name,$value) instead of attributes[] and in the foreach statement $xmlNode->children() needs parenthesis.
thx again!

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml_data = preg_replace("/<([^\/]+\w+)/", "<\\1 attr=\"myAttr\">", $xml_data);
```

Comment: arrrg it's almost doing the trick, excep that this adds 'attr="myAttr">' in the CDATA part of each nodes, but not as an attribute... any idea?

Comment: Yes, this is *why* people recommend not mixing regexes and XML, because of the corner cases and equivalent syntaxes. But don't worry, you're only going to use it on absolutely 100% legal and consistent XML, right?

Answer (score 0):

OK, for those reading these lines and are still interested about using the regex way for some reasons, here is how to do it:

```
$xml_data= preg_replace('/(<[A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+[^>]*)>/u','\1 attr="myAttr">',$xmlData);
```

But, as discussed earlier, use that one with caution!
Use it only on XML source that you know won't be broken (see [soulmerge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357357/regexp-to-add-attribute-in-any-xml-tags/1357393#1357393) post about that)