# PHP regular expression to remove tags in HTML document

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, html-parsing

Say I have the following text

```
..(content).............
<A HREF="http://foo.com/content" >blah blah blah </A>
...(continue content)...
```

I want to delete the link and I want to delete the  tag (while keeping the text in between). How do I do this with a regular expression (since the URLs will all be different)

Much thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-rege)

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Avoid regular expressions whenever you can, [especially when processing xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357357/regexp-to-add-attribute-in-any-xml-tags/1357393#1357393). In this case you can use [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) or [simplexml](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php), depending on your string.

Answer (score 18):

This will remove all tags:

```
preg_replace("/<.*?>/", "", $string);
```

This will remove just the `<a>` tags:

```
preg_replace("/<\\/?a(\\s+.*?>|>)/", "", $string);
```

Comment: won't that wipe out every tag?

Comment: isn't that what was asked for?

Comment: perfect! direct and strict.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
//example to extract the innerText from all anchors in a string
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = str_get_html('<A HREF="http://foo.com/content" >blah blah blah </A><A HREF="http://foo.com/content" >blah blah blah </A>');

//print the text of each anchor    
foreach($html->find('a') as $e) {
    echo $e->innerText;
}
?>
```

See [PHP Simple DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 3):

Not pretty but does the job:

```
$data = str_replace('</a>', '', $data);
$data = preg_replace('/<a[^>]+href[^>]+>/', '', $data);
```

Comment: strip_tags works well when HTML il well formed. I had the problem with an HTML file where attributes were missing quotes, and this approach worked. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`strip_tags()` can also be used.

Please see examples [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may answer the question, [it would be better](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @senderle, I generally agree with you but this time it's not "any" external page, it's PHP.net's official page which describes `strip_tag` function and copying code samples here isn't necessary ;) This answer already contains function name and its link-reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
$pattern = '/href="([^"]*)"/';
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this to replace the anchors with a text string...

```
function replaceAnchorsWithText($data) {
        $regex  = '/(<a\s*'; // Start of anchor tag
        $regex .= '(.*?)\s*'; // Any attributes or spaces that may or may not exist
        $regex .= 'href=[\'"]+?\s*(?P<link>\S+)\s*[\'"]+?'; // Grab the link
        $regex .= '\s*(.*?)\s*>\s*'; // Any attributes or spaces that may or may not exist before closing tag
        $regex .= '(?P<name>\S+)'; // Grab the name
        $regex .= '\s*<\/a>)/i'; // Any number of spaces between the closing anchor tag (case insensitive)

        if (is_array($data)) {
            // This is what will replace the link (modify to you liking)
            $data = "{$data['name']}({$data['link']})";
        }
        return preg_replace_callback($regex, array('self', 'replaceAnchorsWithText'), $data);
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

use str_replace

Comment: how should he do this with different href strings ?

Comment: (I'm not the downvoter, but as it seems he will not explain why he downvoted, which is not that helpful, might I add, let's guess why...) With str_replace, you cannot specify a "pattern", which is a problem, as the URL can change ; and even if it did not change, you'd have to use two calls to str_replace : one for the openig tag, and one for the closing one, as you want to keep what is beetween.