# How replace a character with another character in css?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

i want to display with help css a character with another character. In my page wordpress i have a code like this:

```
</span>
                <span class="address-place">
                 <?php echo the_excerpt (); ?>
                 <hr>
            </span>
```

This code display this line:

> < p >Adult Care Home in SE Portland hiring a live-in caregiver; must
>   speak English, be able to perform the job duties…

I want to replace < p > with another character like nothing or something else in css? I don't need to display that character in my description and i want to hide him but in css because my edit page generate < p > tags.

Display image in site:
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Do that in PHP. It is not possible as far as I am aware with CSS (and should not be possible because CSS is just a styling language).

Comment: In try with php and doesn't work, i want css.

Comment: There's a setting in WP to turn off the `p` wrapping as I recall...if not there are plugins that will do it for you. - https://davidwalsh.name/disable-autop

Comment: Like Harry already said, it's not possible to do that in CSS. Because CSS is styling only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS cannot manipulate text; it's purely a language for styling your content.

But you're using PHP — just have the PHP output whatever you wanted in the first place.

```
<?php echo str_replace('p>', 'whatever>', get_the_excerpt()); ?>
```

Comment: Or you can do something like: `preg_replace("/<\\/?p(\\s+.*?>|>)/", "", $string);` Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364974/php-regular-expression-to-remove-tags-in-html-document

Comment: Ok, work but just for words, if i put <?php echo str_replace('Adult', 'whatever>', get_the_excerpt()); ?> change with 'whatever' but for <p> doesn't work, i put a image in post. Thanks

Comment: `str_replace()` doesn't care what you're replacing — if you replace a string that's found in your content, it'll work.

Comment: I understand but he still <p>, i don't know what i miss

Comment: The `<p>` in your image is literally visible on the page. That wouldn't be a `<p>` in the markup; that would be a `&lt;p&gt;`.

Comment: Greate work with &lt;p&gt;. Thanks a lot, and i want to change two characters? I also have <strong> tag

Answer (score 1):

Function [`the_excerpt()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_excerpt) was echo in return, so don't use echo ( recommended to used in wp loop ). If you need to use echo, use function [`get_the_excerpt()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt).

If you have issue html not decode properly, use `wp_specialchars_decode`. Here the options that you can achieve:

**Filter `the_excerpt`, put this code into `functions.php`**

```
    add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpse221201_get_the_excerpt', 1, 1 );
    function wpse221201_get_the_excerpt( $content )
    {
        if ( ! is_admin() )
            return wp_specialchars_decode( $content );

         return $content;
    }
```

**Or direct decode into function**

```
echo wp_specialchars_decode( get_the_excerpt() );
```

Comment: Thanks, that help me.