# Extract a certain div in HTML using Java+RegEx

Tags: java, regex

I want to parse an HTML document and extract a certain div block that can be repeated.

I've managed to extract THE FIRST occurrence of the block, but I cant figure out how to get the next.

This is my code so far:

```
            String inputStr = HTTPGetter.get("http://someurl");
        String patternStr ="<div class=\"MY-CLASS\">(.*?)</div>";
        // Compile and use regular expression

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
        boolean matchFound = matcher.find();

        if (matchFound) {
            // Get all groups for this match
            for (int i=0; i<=matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                String groupStr = matcher.group(i);
            System.out.println("Group found:\n"+groupStr);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not found");
        }
```

The document I'm parsing has more than one div block of class MY-CLASS. I want to get all of them.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `find()` in a `while` loop:

```
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Group found:\n"+matcher.group(1));
}
```

It's the **matches** you need to iterate through, not the capture groups.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that you do not want to use an [xml parser](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+parse+xml)? [Regular expressions are really not suitable for non-regular languages like xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357357/regexp-to-add-attribute-in-any-xml-tags/1357393#1357393).

Comment: There are also plenty of HTML parsers: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+html+parser

Answer (score 1):

I would **strongly** recommend against using regexps for all but the simplest cases, since HTML is not regular and there are numerous edge cases to trip up your expressions (see numerous answers *passim*).

Take a look at [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/), which will parse the HTML and present a DOM interface for you to interrogate.