# RegEx to get attributes and body of script tags

Tags: html, regex

I'm using this regex to find <script> tags:

```
<script (.|\n)*>(.|\n)*?</script>
```

The problem is, it matches the ENTIRE string below, not just each tag separately:

```
<script src="crap2.js"></script><script src="crap2.js"></script>
```

Comment: Try: `<script[^>]*>[^<]*</script>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

change your first * to *?

This is the non-greedy 'match all', so it will match the smallest set of characters before the next '>'.

Comment: while i agree with JS Bangs' link, im pretty sure this will fix his problem

Comment: If someone comes to a gunfight with a dull knife, will sharpening it fix his problem?

Comment: @Svante: yes, as long as there are no bullets :)

Comment: @TheSean: And I guess with "bullets", you mean things like javascript strings containing '</script>'? Basically, you are *assuming* there are no bullets. But if you value your life: Run if you see a gun pointed at you!

Answer (score 8):

You really would be better off using the DOM to process HTML for this reason and all sorts of others.

Comment: If you're not processing HTML, why did you tag your question as HTML-related?

Comment: Because it's HTML-[i]related[/i].

Answer (score 7):

I don't think anything else needs to be said other than [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: That is probably the best answer I've seen to any question!

Comment: That’s rather a comment than an answer.

Comment: This is a terrible answer. Look, I'm not trying to use regex to parse <b>XHTML</b>. I'm trying to match the <b>string</b> &lt;script ...&gt;&lt;/script&gt;. That is perfectly within the capabilities of regex.

Comment: JamesBrownIsDead, except that you need to care for case, whitespaces, HTML comments, strings inside embedded scripts, `<pre>` regions...   Parsing HTML is a solved problem.

Comment: You *are* parsing HTML. If you weren't, there wouldn't be <script> tags in it.

Answer (score 7):

Also see this week's Coding Horror: [Parsing Html The Cthulhu Way](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/), inspired by the epic [answer by @bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) that @JS Bangs links to.

Answer (score 2):

[I'll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729531/regex-to-trap-img-tag-both-versions/1729558#1729558) [keep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524377/what-regex-pattern-do-i-need-for-this/1524443#1524443) [posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393679/extract-a-certain-div-in-html-using-javaregex/1393780#1393780) [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357357/regexp-to-add-attribute-in-any-xml-tags/1357393#1357393) [to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042833/i-want-to-capture-all-tags-not-having-a-specific-tag/1042909#1042909) [my](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364974/php-regular-expression-to-remove-tags-in-html-document/1365023#1365023) [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417795/replacing-image-src-in-html-tags/1417805#1417805) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380041/regex-for-html-attributes-in-php/1380123#1380123) until this question type has been wiped from this planet's surface (hopefully in 10 years or so): Don't user regular expressions for irregular languages like html or xml. Use a parser instead.

Comment: Any regular expression you create will match a closing script tag in your javascript, for example, so: Yes, you *are* parsing a language.

Comment: Another approach: You are parsing XML, which *is* a language. (or a sub-set of XML - XML documents must have a single root node, which your string doesn't)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script[\s\S]*?>[\s\S]*?</script>
```

This matches most common situations, but it's **very** important to consider [JS Bangs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750567/regex-to-match-script-tag/1750594#1750594).

Answer (score -1):

try to exclude any '<' from the content

```
 <script (.|\n)*>(.|\n|[^<])*?</script>
```

Comment: Even if it's technically not valid valid HTML, people often write code like: `<script>if(a < b) { /* code */ }</script>`

Comment: You're not excluding `<` from the content with `(.|\n|[^<])*?`. The negated character class will never be reached when an occurrence of a `<` is stumbled upon since the `.` meta character already matches it. In fact, the only character will be `\r` (carriage feed) that `[^<]` is going to match.