# Use preg_match to find if string contains script-tags

Tags: php, regex, scripting

How do I write a pattern to use with PHP's preg_match function to check if a string containing script-tags?

Comment: By 'script tags' do you mean things like <script>, <?, <?php, <% and so forth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to escape them? if so try the following (not tested)

```
$string=str_replace(array("&", "<", ">"), array("&amp;", "&lt;", "&gt;"), $string);
```

With this way a surprise will be waiting your attackers.

Comment: I'm trying to check if containg script-tag (true/false).

Comment: then this might work: preg_match("/<script.*?</script>/i", $string);

Comment: Or simply `htmlspecialchars`.

Comment: A shame using str_replace when htmlspecialchars is available :)

Answer (score 4):

For security reasons? Basically, you can't. Here are some things I learned doing this in the past:

- `<a href="javascript:something">...</a>`
- `<p onmouseover="something">`
- There are a number of URL schemes that are equivalent to `javascript:` in different browsers, like `jscript:`, `mocha:`, and `livescript:`. Most are undocumented.
- Old versions of Netscape treated certain bytes (0x94 and 0x95, I think?) as equivalent to `<>`. Hopefully there's nothing like this in modern browsers.
- VBScript.

MySpace tried to do this, and the result was the "Samy is my hero" worm which took down the service for a day or so, among numerous other security disasters on their part.

So if you want to accept a limited subset of HTML that only includes text and formatting, you have to *whitelist*, not *blacklist*. You have to whitelist tags, attributes, and if you want to allow links, URL schemes. There are a few existing libraries out there for doing this, but I don't know which ones to recommend in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

[Don't use regular expressions for processing xml/html.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357357/regexp-to-add-attribute-in-any-xml-tags/1357393#1357393) You should rather use the [DOM classes of PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), it should be much more reliable than any regex you will find:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHtml($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($document);
if ($xpath->query('//script')->length > 0) {
    // document contains script tags
}
```

Comment: The question simply says "string", which does not necessarily imply that there is a document structure...