# How to get href from anchor tag with particular class

Tags: php, html, parsing

If I have an HTML document, what is the best way to go through the document and gather the href values from all anchor tags with a particular class using PHP?

Comment: If you want to query an XML document, you can use XPath. And HTML is not far from being an XML (you can tidy it if it is not, with... tidy).
The SimpleXML extension [provides such a functionality](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php)

Comment: almost a duplicate of [Preg_match_all <a href](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519696/preg-match-all-a-href)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [soulmerge's answer to "Preg_match_all href"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519696/preg-match-all-a-href/1519791#1519791). Adjust the XPath to

```
//a[@class="foo"]/@href
```

to get a DOMNodeList of all href attributes belonging to  elements with a class of `foo`.