# html parser for php?

Tags: php, html, parsing, html-parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best methods to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html)
>   [How to get href from anchor tag with particular class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232219/how-to-get-href-from-anchor-tag-with-particular-class/3232360#3232360)

hi guys,

I need an html parser. Baiscally given an html in a string i need to extract every href of

Which html parser for php do u suggest me? Someone that handles wrong html too.

Thanks

Comment: Please search for existing questions/answers before you post a new question - this topic has already been covered in some detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/domdocument), it's often (always?) compiled with PHP 5.

You can use [DOMXpath](http://php.net/domxpath) for extracting all `href` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) is the best tool I have tested to parse HTML and extract data.

Comment: how many others did you test? ;) Suggested third party alternatives to [SimpleHtmlDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) that actually use [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead of String Parsing: [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), [Zend_Dom](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.html), [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) and [FluentDom](http://www.fluentdom.org).