# read contents of an external webpage and get specific elements

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

I've tried to figure this out for awhile now. I'm trying to not only get the contents of a webpage using `file_get_contents($url)` but also be able to draw out specific data.

A webpage I was interested in grabbing the contents of, is [Craiglist](http://www.craigslist.org/about/sites).  This is just one example.  I'd like to form an array of states with areas and accompanying websites, but I cant seem to find the way to get the specific elements of the page.  Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php) - and this has been asked just an hour ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428504/extracting-values-from-string-with-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Example getting all link from `http://www.craigslist.org/about/sites`

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$url = "http://www.craigslist.org/about/sites";
$html = file_get_html ( $url );
echo "<pre>";
foreach ( $html->find ( 'a' ) as $element ) {
    $link = $element->href;
    $link = ltrim ( $link, "/" );

    if (!preg_match ( "/http/i", $link )) {
        $link = $url . $link;
    }
    echo $link . PHP_EOL;
    flush ();
}
```

Output

```
http://www.craigslist.org/about/sites#US
http://www.craigslist.org/about/sites#CA
http://www.craigslist.org/about/sites#EU
http://www.craigslist.org/about/sites#ASIA
http://www.craigslist.org/about/sites#OCEANIA
http://www.craigslist.org/about/sites#LATAM
http://www.craigslist.org/about/sites#AF
http://www.craigslist.org/about/sites
http://auburn.craigslist.org
http://bham.craigslist.org
http://dothan.craigslist.org
http://shoals.craigslist.org
http://gadsden.craigslist.org
http://huntsville.craigslist.org
http://mobile.craigslist.org
http://montgomery.craigslist.org
http://tuscaloosa.craigslist.org
http://anchorage.craigslist.org
http://fairbanks.craigslist.org
http://kenai.craigslist.org
http://juneau.craigslist.org
http://flagstaff.craigslist.org
http://mohave.craigslist.org
http://phoenix.craigslist.org
http://prescott.craigslist.org
http://showlow.craigslist.org
http://sierravista.craigslist.org
http://tucson.craigslist.org
http://yuma.craigslist.org
http://fayar.craigslist.org
http://fortsmith.craigslist.org
http://jonesboro.craigslist.org
http://littlerock.craigslist.org
http://texarkana.craigslist.org
http://bakersfield.craigslist.org
http://chico.craigslist.org
http://fresno.craigslist.org
http://goldcountry.craigslist.org
http://hanford.craigslist.org
http://humboldt.craigslist.org
http://imperial.craigslist.org
http://inlandempire.craigslist.org
http://losangeles.craigslist.org
http://mendocino.craigslist.org
http://merced.craigslist.org
http://modesto.craigslist.org
http://monterey.craigslist.org
http://orangecounty.craigslist.org
http://palmsprings.craigslist.org
http://redding.craigslist.org
http://sacramento.craigslist.org
http://sandiego.craigslist.org
http://sfbay.craigslist.org
http://slo.craigslist.org
http://santabarbara.craigslist.org
http://santamaria.craigslist.org
http://siskiyou.craigslist.org
http://stockton.craigslist.org
http://susanville.craigslist.org
http://ventura.craigslist.org
http://visalia.craigslist.org
http://yubasutter.craigslist.org
http://boulder.craigslist.org
http://cosprings.craigslist.org
http://denver.craigslist.org
http://eastco.craigslist.org
http://fortcollins.craigslist.org
http://rockies.craigslist.org
http://pueblo.craigslist.org
http://westslope.craigslist.org
http://newlondon.craigslist.org
http://hartford.craigslist.org
http://newhaven.craigslist.org
http://nwct.craigslist.org
http://delaware.craigslist.org
http://washingtondc.craigslist.org
http://daytona.craigslist.org
http://keys.craigslist.org
http://fortlauderdale.craigslist.org
http://fortmyers.craigslist.org
http://gainesville.craigslist.org
http://cfl.craigslist.org
http://jacksonville.craigslist.org
http://lakeland.craigslist.org
http://lakecity.craigslist.org
http://ocala.craigslist.org
http://okaloosa.craigslist.org
http://orlando.craigslist.org
http://panamacity.craigslist.org
http://pensacola.craigslist.org
http://sarasota.craigslist.org
http://miami.craigslist.org
http://spacecoast.craigslist.org
http://staugustine.craigslist.org
http://tallahassee.craigslist.org
http://tampa.craigslist.org
http://treasure.craigslist.org
http://westpalmbeach.craigslist.org
http://albanyga.craigslist.org
http://athensga.craigslist.org
http://atlanta.craigslist.org
http://augusta.craigslist.org
http://brunswick.craigslist.org
http://columbusga.craigslist.org
http://macon.craigslist.org
http://nwga.craigslist.org
http://savannah.craigslist.org
http://statesboro.craigslist.org
http://valdosta.craigslist.org
http://honolulu.craigslist.org
http://boise.craigslist.org
http://eastidaho.craigslist.org
http://lewiston.craigslist.org
http://twinfalls.craigslist.org
http://bn.craigslist.org
http://chambana.craigslist.org
http://chicago.craigslist.org
http://decatur.craigslist.org
http://lasalle.craigslist.org
http://mattoon.craigslist.org
http://peoria.craigslist.org
http://rockford.craigslist.org
http://carbondale.craigslist.org
http://springfieldil.craigslist.org
http://quincy.craigslist.org
http://bloomington.craigslist.org
http://evansville.craigslist.org
http://fortwayne.craigslist.org
http://indianapolis.craigslist.org
http://kokomo.craigslist.org
http://tippecanoe.craigslist.org
http://muncie.craigslist.org
http://richmondin.craigslist.org
http://southbend.craigslist.org
http://terrehaute.craigslist.org
http://ames.craigslist.org
http://cedarrapids.craigslist.org
http://desmoines.craigslist.org
http://dubuque.craigslist.org
http://fortdodge.craigslist.org
http://iowacity.craigslist.org
http://masoncity.craigslist.org
http://quadcities.craigslist.org
http://siouxcity.craigslist.org
http://ottumwa.craigslist.org
http://waterloo.craigslist.org
http://lawrence.craigslist.org
http://ksu.craigslist.org
http://nwks.craigslist.org
http://salina.craigslist.org
http://seks.craigslist.org
http://swks.craigslist.org
http://topeka.craigslist.org
http://wichita.craigslist.org
http://bgky.craigslist.org
http://eastky.craigslist.org
http://lexington.craigslist.org
http://louisville.craigslist.org
http://owensboro.craigslist.org
http://westky.craigslist.org
http://batonrouge.craigslist.org
http://cenla.craigslist.org
http://houma.craigslist.org
http://lafayette.craigslist.org
http://lakecharles.craigslist.org
http://monroe.craigslist.org
http://neworleans.craigslist.org
http://shreveport.craigslist.org
http://maine.craigslist.org
http://annapolis.craigslist.org
http://baltimore.craigslist.org
http://easternshore.craigslist.org
http://frederick.craigslist.org
http://smd.craigslist.org
http://westmd.craigslist.org
http://boston.craigslist.org
http://capecod.craigslist.org
http://southcoast.craigslist.org
http://westernmass.craigslist.org
http://worcester.craigslist.org
http://annarbor.craigslist.org
http://battlecreek.craigslist.org
http://centralmich.craigslist.org
http://detroit.craigslist.org
http://flint.craigslist.org
http://grandrapids.craigslist.org
http://holland.craigslist.org
http://jxn.craigslist.org
http://kalamazoo.craigslist.org
http://lansing.craigslist.org
http://monroemi.craigslist.org
http://muskegon.craigslist.org
http://nmi.craigslist.org
http://porthuron.craigslist.org
http://saginaw.craigslist.org
http://swmi.craigslist.org
http://thumb.craigslist.org
http://up.craigslist.org
http://bemidji.craigslist.org
http://brainerd.craigslist.org
http://duluth.craigslist.org
http://mankato.craigslist.org
http://minneapolis.craigslist.org
http://rmn.craigslist.org
http://marshall.craigslist.org
http://stcloud.craigslist.org
http://gulfport.craigslist.org
http://hattiesburg.craigslist.org
http://jackson.craigslist.org
http://meridian.craigslist.org
http://northmiss.craigslist.org
http://natchez.craigslist.org
http://columbiamo.craigslist.org
http://joplin.craigslist.org
http://kansascity.craigslist.org
http://kirksville.craigslist.org
http://loz.craigslist.org
http://semo.craigslist.org
http://springfield.craigslist.org
http://stjoseph.craigslist.org
http://stlouis.craigslist.org
http://billings.craigslist.org
http://bozeman.craigslist.org
http://butte.craigslist.org
http://greatfalls.craigslist.org
http://helena.craigslist.org
http://kalispell.craigslist.org
http://missoula.craigslist.org
http://montana.craigslist.org
http://grandisland.craigslist.org
http://lincoln.craigslist.org
http://northplatte.craigslist.org
http://omaha.craigslist.org
http://scottsbluff.craigslist.org
http://elko.craigslist.org
http://lasvegas.craigslist.org
http://reno.craigslist.org
http://nh.craigslist.org
http://cnj.craigslist.org
http://jerseyshore.craigslist.org
http://newjersey.craigslist.org
http://southjersey.craigslist.org
http://albuquerque.craigslist.org
http://clovis.craigslist.org
http://farmington.craigslist.org
http://lascruces.craigslist.org
http://roswell.craigslist.org
http://santafe.craigslist.org
http://albany.craigslist.org
http://binghamton.craigslist.org
http://buffalo.craigslist.org
http://catskills.craigslist.org
http://chautauqua.craigslist.org
http://elmira.craigslist.org
http://fingerlakes.craigslist.org
http://glensfalls.craigslist.org
http://hudsonvalley.craigslist.org
http://ithaca.craigslist.org
http://longisland.craigslist.org
http://newyork.craigslist.org
http://oneonta.craigslist.org
http://plattsburgh.craigslist.org
http://potsdam.craigslist.org
http://rochester.craigslist.org
http://syracuse.craigslist.org
http://twintiers.craigslist.org
http://utica.craigslist.org
http://watertown.craigslist.org
http://asheville.craigslist.org
http://boone.craigslist.org
http://charlotte.craigslist.org
http://eastnc.craigslist.org
http://fayetteville.craigslist.org
http://greensboro.craigslist.org
http://hickory.craigslist.org
http://onslow.craigslist.org
http://outerbanks.craigslist.org
http://raleigh.craigslist.org
http://wilmington.craigslist.org
http://winstonsalem.craigslist.org
http://bismarck.craigslist.org
http://fargo.craigslist.org
http://grandforks.craigslist.org
http://nd.craigslist.org
http://akroncanton.craigslist.org
http://ashtabula.craigslist.org
http://athensohio.craigslist.org
http://chillicothe.craigslist.org
http://cincinnati.craigslist.org
http://cleveland.craigslist.org
http://columbus.craigslist.org
http://dayton.craigslist.org
http://limaohio.craigslist.org
http://mansfield.craigslist.org
http://sandusky.craigslist.org
http://toledo.craigslist.org
http://tuscarawas.craigslist.org
http://youngstown.craigslist.org
http://zanesville.craigslist.org
http://lawton.craigslist.org
http://enid.craigslist.org
http://oklahomacity.craigslist.org
http://stillwater.craigslist.org
http://tulsa.craigslist.org
http://bend.craigslist.org
http://corvallis.craigslist.org
http://eastoregon.craigslist.org
http://eugene.craigslist.org
http://klamath.craigslist.org
http://medford.craigslist.org
http://oregoncoast.craigslist.org
http://portland.craigslist.org
http://roseburg.craigslist.org
http://salem.craigslist.org
http://altoona.craigslist.org
http://chambersburg.craigslist.org
http://erie.craigslist.org
http://harrisburg.craigslist.org
http://lancaster.craigslist.org
http://allentown.craigslist.org
http://meadville.craigslist.org
http://philadelphia.craigslist.org
http://pittsburgh.craigslist.org
http://poconos.craigslist.org
http://reading.craigslist.org
http://scranton.craigslist.org
http://pennstate.craigslist.org
http://williamsport.craigslist.org
http://york.craigslist.org
http://providence.craigslist.org
http://charleston.craigslist.org
http://columbia.craigslist.org
http://florencesc.craigslist.org
http://greenville.craigslist.org
http://hiltonhead.craigslist.org
http://myrtlebeach.craigslist.org
http://nesd.craigslist.org
http://csd.craigslist.org
http://rapidcity.craigslist.org
http://siouxfalls.craigslist.org
http://sd.craigslist.org
http://chattanooga.craigslist.org
http://clarksville.craigslist.org
http://cookeville.craigslist.org
http://jacksontn.craigslist.org
http://knoxville.craigslist.org
http://memphis.craigslist.org
http://nashville.craigslist.org
http://tricities.craigslist.org
http://abilene.craigslist.org
http://amarillo.craigslist.org
http://austin.craigslist.org
http://beaumont.craigslist.org
http://brownsville.craigslist.org
http://collegestation.craigslist.org
http://corpuschristi.craigslist.org
http://dallas.craigslist.org
http://nacogdoches.craigslist.org
http://delrio.craigslist.org
http://elpaso.craigslist.org
http://galveston.craigslist.org
http://houston.craigslist.org
http://killeen.craigslist.org
http://laredo.craigslist.org
http://lubbock.craigslist.org
http://mcallen.craigslist.org
http://odessa.craigslist.org
http://sanangelo.craigslist.org
http://sanantonio.craigslist.org
http://sanmarcos.craigslist.org
http://bigbend.craigslist.org
http://texoma.craigslist.org
http://easttexas.craigslist.org
http://victoriatx.craigslist.org
http://waco.craigslist.org
http://wichitafalls.craigslist.org
http://logan.craigslist.org
http://ogden.craigslist.org
http://provo.craigslist.org
http://saltlakecity.craigslist.org
http://stgeorge.craigslist.org
http://burlington.craigslist.org
http://charlottesville.craigslist.org
http://danville.craigslist.org
http://fredericksburg.craigslist.org
http://norfolk.craigslist.org
http://harrisonburg.craigslist.org
http://lynchburg.craigslist.org
http://blacksburg.craigslist.org
http://richmond.craigslist.org
http://roanoke.craigslist.org
http://swva.craigslist.org
http://winchester.craigslist.org
http://bellingham.craigslist.org
http://kpr.craigslist.org
http://moseslake.craigslist.org
http://olympic.craigslist.org
http://pullman.craigslist.org
http://seattle.craigslist.org
http://skagit.craigslist.org
http://spokane.craigslist.org
http://wenatchee.craigslist.org
http://yakima.craigslist.org
http://charlestonwv.craigslist.org
http://martinsburg.craigslist.org
http://huntington.craigslist.org
http://morgantown.craigslist.org
http://wheeling.craigslist.org
http://parkersburg.craigslist.org
http://swv.craigslist.org
http://wv.craigslist.org
http://appleton.craigslist.org
http://eauclaire.craigslist.org
http://greenbay.craigslist.org
http://janesville.craigslist.org
http://racine.craigslist.org
http://lacrosse.craigslist.org
http://madison.craigslist.org
http://milwaukee.craigslist.org
http://northernwi.craigslist.org
http://sheboygan.craigslist.org
http://wausau.craigslist.org
http://wyoming.craigslist.org
http://micronesia.craigslist.org
http://puertorico.craigslist.org
http://virgin.craigslist.org
http://www.craigslist.org/about/sites
http://calgary.craigslist.ca
http://edmonton.craigslist.ca
http://ftmcmurray.craigslist.ca
http://lethbridge.craigslist.ca
http://hat.craigslist.ca
http://peace.craigslist.ca
http://reddeer.craigslist.ca
http://cariboo.craigslist.ca
http://comoxvalley.craigslist.ca
http://abbotsford.craigslist.ca
http://kamloops.craigslist.ca
http://kelowna.craigslist.ca
http://cranbrook.craigslist.ca
http://nanaimo.craigslist.ca
http://princegeorge.craigslist.ca
http://skeena.craigslist.ca
http://sunshine.craigslist.ca
http://vancouver.craigslist.ca
http://victoria.craigslist.ca
http://whistler.craigslist.ca
http://winnipeg.craigslist.ca
http://newbrunswick.craigslist.ca
http://newfoundland.craigslist.ca
http://territories.craigslist.ca
http://yellowknife.craigslist.ca
http://halifax.craigslist.ca
http://barrie.craigslist.ca
http://belleville.craigslist.ca
http://brantford.craigslist.ca
http://chatham.craigslist.ca
http://cornwall.craigslist.ca
http://guelph.craigslist.ca
http://hamilton.craigslist.ca
http://kingston.craigslist.ca
http://kitchener.craigslist.ca
http://londonon.craigslist.ca
http://niagara.craigslist.ca
http://ottawa.craigslist.ca
http://owensound.craigslist.ca
http://peterborough.craigslist.ca
http://sarnia.craigslist.ca
http://soo.craigslist.ca
http://sudbury.craigslist.ca
http://thunderbay.craigslist.ca
http://toronto.craigslist.ca
http://windsor.craigslist.ca
http://pei.craigslist.ca
http://montreal.craigslist.ca
http://quebec.craigslist.ca
http://saguenay.craigslist.ca
http://sherbrooke.craigslist.ca
http://troisrivieres.craigslist.ca
http://regina.craigslist.ca
http://saskatoon.craigslist.ca
http://whitehorse.craigslist.ca
http://www.craigslist.org/about/sites
http://vienna.craigslist.at
http://brussels.craigslist.org
http://bulgaria.craigslist.org
http://zagreb.craigslist.org
http://prague.craigslist.cz
http://copenhagen.craigslist.org
http://helsinki.craigslist.fi
http://bordeaux.craigslist.org
http://rennes.craigslist.org
http://grenoble.craigslist.org
http://lille.craigslist.org
http://loire.craigslist.org
http://lyon.craigslist.org
http://marseilles.craigslist.org
http://montpellier.craigslist.org
http://cotedazur.craigslist.org
http://rouen.craigslist.org
http://paris.craigslist.org
http://strasbourg.craigslist.org
http://toulouse.craigslist.org
http://berlin.craigslist.de
http://bremen.craigslist.de
http://cologne.craigslist.de
http://dresden.craigslist.de
http://dusseldorf.craigslist.de
http://essen.craigslist.de
http://frankfurt.craigslist.de
http://hamburg.craigslist.de
http://hannover.craigslist.de
http://heidelberg.craigslist.de
http://kaiserslautern.craigslist.de
http://leipzig.craigslist.de
http://munich.craigslist.de
http://nuremberg.craigslist.de
http://stuttgart.craigslist.de
http://athens.craigslist.gr
http://budapest.craigslist.org
http://reykjavik.craigslist.org
http://dublin.craigslist.org
http://bologna.craigslist.it
http://florence.craigslist.it
http://genoa.craigslist.it
http://milan.craigslist.it
http://naples.craigslist.it
http://perugia.craigslist.it
http://rome.craigslist.it
http://sardinia.craigslist.it
http://sicily.craigslist.it
http://torino.craigslist.it
http://venice.craigslist.it
http://luxembourg.craigslist.org
http://amsterdam.craigslist.org
http://oslo.craigslist.org
http://warsaw.craigslist.pl
http://faro.craigslist.pt
http://lisbon.craigslist.pt
http://porto.craigslist.pt
http://bucharest.craigslist.org
http://moscow.craigslist.org
http://stpetersburg.craigslist.org
http://alicante.craigslist.es
http://baleares.craigslist.es
http://barcelona.craigslist.es
http://bilbao.craigslist.es
http://cadiz.craigslist.es
http://canarias.craigslist.es
http://granada.craigslist.es
http://madrid.craigslist.es
http://malaga.craigslist.es
http://sevilla.craigslist.es
http://valencia.craigslist.es
http://stockholm.craigslist.se
http://basel.craigslist.ch
http://bern.craigslist.ch
http://geneva.craigslist.ch
http://lausanne.craigslist.ch
http://zurich.craigslist.ch
http://istanbul.craigslist.com.tr
http://ukraine.craigslist.org
http://aberdeen.craigslist.co.uk
http://bath.craigslist.co.uk
http://belfast.craigslist.co.uk
http://birmingham.craigslist.co.uk
http://brighton.craigslist.co.uk
http://bristol.craigslist.co.uk
http://cambridge.craigslist.co.uk
http://cardiff.craigslist.co.uk
http://coventry.craigslist.co.uk
http://derby.craigslist.co.uk
http://devon.craigslist.co.uk
http://dundee.craigslist.co.uk
http://norwich.craigslist.co.uk
http://eastmids.craigslist.co.uk
http://edinburgh.craigslist.co.uk
http://essex.craigslist.co.uk
http://glasgow.craigslist.co.uk
http://hampshire.craigslist.co.uk
http://kent.craigslist.co.uk
http://leeds.craigslist.co.uk
http://liverpool.craigslist.co.uk
http://london.craigslist.co.uk
http://manchester.craigslist.co.uk
http://newcastle.craigslist.co.uk
http://nottingham.craigslist.co.uk
http://oxford.craigslist.co.uk
http://sheffield.craigslist.co.uk
http://www.craigslist.org/about/sites
http://micronesia.craigslist.org
http://bangladesh.craigslist.org
http://beijing.craigslist.com.cn
http://chengdu.craigslist.com.cn
http://chongqing.craigslist.com.cn
http://dalian.craigslist.com.cn
http://guangzhou.craigslist.com.cn
http://hangzhou.craigslist.com.cn
http://nanjing.craigslist.com.cn
http://shanghai.craigslist.com.cn
http://shenyang.craigslist.com.cn
http://shenzhen.craigslist.com.cn
http://wuhan.craigslist.com.cn
http://xian.craigslist.com.cn
http://hongkong.craigslist.hk
http://ahmedabad.craigslist.co.in
http://bangalore.craigslist.co.in
http://bhubaneswar.craigslist.co.in
http://chandigarh.craigslist.co.in
http://chennai.craigslist.co.in
http://delhi.craigslist.co.in
http://goa.craigslist.co.in
http://hyderabad.craigslist.co.in
http://indore.craigslist.co.in
http://jaipur.craigslist.co.in
http://kerala.craigslist.co.in
http://kolkata.craigslist.co.in
http://lucknow.craigslist.co.in
http://mumbai.craigslist.co.in
http://pune.craigslist.co.in
http://surat.craigslist.co.in
http://jakarta.craigslist.org
http://tehran.craigslist.org
http://baghdad.craigslist.org
http://haifa.craigslist.org
http://jerusalem.craigslist.org
http://telaviv.craigslist.org
http://ramallah.craigslist.org
http://fukuoka.craigslist.jp
http://hiroshima.craigslist.jp
http://nagoya.craigslist.jp
http://okinawa.craigslist.jp
http://osaka.craigslist.jp
http://sapporo.craigslist.jp
http://sendai.craigslist.jp
http://tokyo.craigslist.jp
http://seoul.craigslist.co.kr
http://kuwait.craigslist.org
http://beirut.craigslist.org
http://malaysia.craigslist.org
http://pakistan.craigslist.org
http://bacolod.craigslist.com.ph
http://naga.craigslist.com.ph
http://cdo.craigslist.com.ph
http://cebu.craigslist.com.ph
http://davaocity.craigslist.com.ph
http://iloilo.craigslist.com.ph
http://manila.craigslist.com.ph
http://pampanga.craigslist.com.ph
http://zamboanga.craigslist.com.ph
http://singapore.craigslist.com.sg
http://taipei.craigslist.com.tw
http://bangkok.craigslist.co.th
http://dubai.craigslist.org
http://vietnam.craigslist.org
http://www.craigslist.org/about/sites
http://adelaide.craigslist.com.au
http://brisbane.craigslist.com.au
http://cairns.craigslist.com.au
http://canberra.craigslist.com.au
http://darwin.craigslist.com.au
http://goldcoast.craigslist.com.au
http://melbourne.craigslist.com.au
http://ntl.craigslist.com.au
http://perth.craigslist.com.au
http://sydney.craigslist.com.au
http://hobart.craigslist.com.au
http://wollongong.craigslist.com.au
http://auckland.craigslist.org
http://christchurch.craigslist.org
http://dunedin.craigslist.co.nz
http://wellington.craigslist.org
http://www.craigslist.org/about/sites
http://caribbean.craigslist.org
http://buenosaires.craigslist.org
http://lapaz.craigslist.org
http://belohorizonte.craigslist.org
http://brasilia.craigslist.org
http://curitiba.craigslist.org
http://fortaleza.craigslist.org
http://portoalegre.craigslist.org
http://recife.craigslist.org
http://rio.craigslist.org
http://salvador.craigslist.org
http://saopaulo.craigslist.org
http://santiago.craigslist.org
http://colombia.craigslist.org
http://costarica.craigslist.org
http://santodomingo.craigslist.org
http://quito.craigslist.org
http://elsalvador.craigslist.org
http://guatemala.craigslist.org
http://acapulco.craigslist.com.mx
http://bajasur.craigslist.com.mx
http://chihuahua.craigslist.com.mx
http://juarez.craigslist.com.mx
http://guadalajara.craigslist.com.mx
http://guanajuato.craigslist.com.mx
http://hermosillo.craigslist.com.mx
http://mazatlan.craigslist.com.mx
http://mexicocity.craigslist.com.mx
http://monterrey.craigslist.com.mx
http://oaxaca.craigslist.com.mx
http://puebla.craigslist.com.mx
http://pv.craigslist.com.mx
http://tijuana.craigslist.com.mx
http://veracruz.craigslist.com.mx
http://yucatan.craigslist.com.mx
http://managua.craigslist.org
http://panama.craigslist.org
http://lima.craigslist.org
http://puertorico.craigslist.org
http://montevideo.craigslist.org
http://caracas.craigslist.org
http://virgin.craigslist.org
http://www.craigslist.org/about/sites
http://cairo.craigslist.org
http://addisababa.craigslist.org
http://accra.craigslist.org
http://kenya.craigslist.org
http://casablanca.craigslist.org
http://capetown.craigslist.co.za
http://durban.craigslist.co.za
http://johannesburg.craigslist.co.za
http://pretoria.craigslist.co.za
http://tunis.craigslist.org
http://www.craigslist.org/about/
http://blog.craigslist.com/
http://www.craigslist.org/about/help/system-status.html
http://www.craigslist.org/about/help/
http://www.craigslist.org/about/terms.of.use
http://www.craigslist.org/about/privacy_policy
http://sfbay.craigslist.org/forums/?forumID=1
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [`DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) class in PHP.

```
<?php
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML("<html><body>Test<br></body></html>");
    echo $doc->saveHTML();
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use domdocument

```
$html = 'Assume this is html that you get';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');  // Sample to get table element
$rows = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr'); // sample to get rows of the table element
```

[Here is the description](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)