# Replace a form in a html file using php

Tags: php, html, forms, file, fopen

I need to identify a form in a html file using php file operation for replacing it with dynamic fields. My initial requirement is to find out a form in a file with php file operation.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you'r looking for something like this which is already answered here.

[read contents of an external webpage and get specific elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430037/read-contents-of-an-external-webpage-and-get-specific-elements)