# Replace all matches that are not part of HTML code

Tags: php, regex

I have input such as:

```
<h2 class="role">He played and an important role</h2>
```

And need to replace the role, but not in the class.

Tricky is, that it may be `class="group role something"` or so, so I essentially only want to search the real text and not the html, but I need to give back everything.

I'm in PHP and do not have a real good starting point ...

Comment: [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: A XML parser might be a better choice than regexp

Comment: possible duplicate of [What regex pattern do I need for this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524377/what-regex-pattern-do-i-need-for-this). The approved answer is all you need.

Comment: I don't know who `str_replace` might help here. I have tried to isolate the html but did not really figure out how to invert that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use the DOM to manipulate HTML, but here is a regex solution.

It will not make the replacement if `>` appears before `<` ahead in the string.

```
$input = '<h2 class="role">He played and an important role</h2>';

$input = preg_replace( '/role(?![^<>]*>[^<>]*(?:<|$))/', 'new role', $input );

echo $input;    
// <h2 class="role">He played and an important new role</h2>
```

Comment: That's cool, but it does not work for `<h2 class="role">He played and an <em>important</em> role</h2>`.

Comment: Hm, not in my PHP Version (5.4.4)

Comment: @shredding. Updated answer following your new example input.

Comment: Okay, this is just one line over multipe lines with recursive calling of methods and looping. I'll take that.

Answer (score 2):

Better no preg_ for parsing HTML, use dom:

```
$input = '<h2 class="role">He played and an important role</h2>';

$dom = new domDocument('1.0', 'utf-8'); 
$dom->loadHTML($input); 
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 

$element = $dom->getElementsByTagName('h2'); // <--- change tag name as appropriate
$value = $element->item(0)->nodeValue;

// change $value here...
```

Comment: I think h2 is just an example HTML, OP wants just any HTML node.

Comment: @anubhava ok, then either change the desired tag (see my edit) or loop through all nodes

Comment: Problem is, that it's only a snippet, not an entire html document.

Comment: @shredding as long as your snipped is not totally screwed html, it should work

Comment: How'd I loop through all nodes? With xpath?

Comment: @shredding welcome! xpath if you have either specific tags or a parent-tag (like <body>) pls post your solution!