# regex to trap img tag, both versions

Tags: c#, regex

I need to remove image tags from text, so both versions of the tag:

```
<img src="" ... ></img>


<img src="" ... />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C# you can use following code:

```
            string html = @"
<h1>
<img src="" ... >
</img>
<img></img>-bad
<img/>-bad
<img src="" ... />
</h1>";
            string result = Regex.Replace(html, @"<img\s[^>]*>(?:\s*?</img>)?", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

But be aware that modifying HTML with Regex isn't good approach, its better to use [Html Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack)
 or other HTML parsers.

Answer (score 4):

This is [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357357/regexp-to-add-attribute-in-any-xml-tags/1357393#1357393) something you do with regular expressions. Use the [xpath](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308333)-query `//img` instead.