# preg_match from some html code

Tags: php, html, regex, parsing, preg-match

How would I write a php preg_match() in php to pick out the 250 value. I have a large string of html code that I want to pick the 250 out of and I can't seem to get the regular expression right.

This is the html pattern I want to match - note that I want to extract the integer where the 250 is:

`<span class="price-ld">H$250</span>`

I have been trying for hours to do this and I can't get it to work lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the regex you're looking for:

```
(?<=<span class="price-ld">H\$)\d+(?=</span>)
```

You can see the results **[here](http://regexr.com?32376)**.

And here's the explanation:

```
Options: case insensitive; ^ and $ match at line breaks

Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind) «(?<=<span class="price-ld">H\$)»
    Match the characters “<span class="price-ld">H” literally «<span class="price-ld">H»
    Match the character “$” literally «\$»
Match a single digit 0..9 «\d+»
    Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) «(?=</span>)»
    Match the characters “</span>” literally «span>»
```

Answer (score 3):

```
preg_match('/<span class="price-ld">H$(\d+)<\/span>/i', $your_html, $matches);
print "Its ".$matches[1]." USD";
```

The regex actually depends on your code. Where are you exactly searching for?

Comment: I literally want to pull any number that comes after H$ where it is surrounded by that specific pattern with the `class="price-ld"`

Comment: This gets a match: `//get the title of the product
preg_match('/<title>(.*)<\/title>/i', $candidate[0], $title);
$p_title = $title[1];`

Comment: But this one doesnt: `//get the price of the product
preg_match('/<span class="price-ld">H$(\d+)<\/span>/i', $candidate[0], $price);
$p_price = $price[1];
echo $p_price;`

Comment: I wonder why your example mentions that new `title` tag. Maybe you need some whitespace tolerance. Minify your regexp like `/class="price-ld"\s*>\s*H$(\d+)/`. Anyway this forces no more HTML comment to be inbetween the tag content and that class. It depends on the page you want to screen scrape what kind of *parsing* you can take. You should post an excerpt somewhere (http://pastebin.com)

Comment: Anyway maybe you should obey the common tip [Don't use regexp to parse HTML, use a real XML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357357/regexp-to-add-attribute-in-any-xml-tags/1357393#1357393).